# Split string by index in JavaScript using direct way like splitting by a regex

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, split

This is kind of a challenge, as I'm sure there must be a better way to do this but I'm not able to find it.

Given a string, I want to split it into two strings by a given index. For instance:

```
input: 
  - string: "helloworld"
  - index: 5
output: ["hello", "world"]
```

An easy way is to make two slices, but isn't there a more direct way like splitting by a regex or something? I would like to achieve my purpose with a single instruction.

The non-elegant way:

```js
const str = "helloworld";
const [ str1, str2 ] = [ str.substring(0, 5), str.substring(5) ];
```

Comment: Dupe doesn't look like what OP is looking for here as OP already knows how to use `slice` or `substring`

Comment: @anubhava The accepted answer with the highest vote-count is the same as your _"Alternative"_ o.O

Comment: But it is not the main solution which is using `split` besides IMO dupe marking has to be on the nature of the problem not the similarity of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```bash
(?<=^.{5})
```

Here `(?<=^.{5})` is a lookbehind assertion that splits at the position that has 5 characters on left hand side after start.

**Code:**

```js
var s = 'helloworld';

var arr = s.split(/(?<=^.{5})/);

console.log(arr);
//=> ['hello', 'world']
```

**Alternatively**, you can use `match + slice`:

```bash
s.match(/^(.{5})(.*)/).slice(1)
```

We must use `.slice(1)` here to discard first element of array which is full match.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```
const splitAt = (index, input) => [input.slice(0, index), input.slice(index)]
```